# Angular restrict service to only one component tree

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-providers, angular-injector

i want to implement a service and let it provide to only one named component or module and not to any other component or module.

So whenever anyone tries to provide that service to another component they get an error and the program should not compile.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I guess you misunderstood my question.
I am saying that no developer shall be able to add that service to any where in providers array except one component tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide it to a component it will only be available to that component and its children:

```
@Component({
  selector: "component",
  providers: [Service]
})
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components.

A way to limit scope to a module or component:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: HelloComponent })
export class Service {}
```

So if this component itself has no children, it is in fact the only named component that has access to it. Other components will receive an Injector Error

Comment: wow it was so simple and i was looking for the answer everywhere. :D Let me check this before marking this as answer. Thanks.

Comment: nopes not working... Even when i put providedIn to a component it gives me circular dependency error. and the child components are also not able to access the service. Angular 11.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Provide the service as a class in a component, it must create one instance for that component, and you can remove the provider from the module.

```
@Component({
  selector: "component",
  providers: [{ provide: Service, useClass: Service }]
})
```

and null injectable, the injectable is not provided in any scope automatically...

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {}
```